# Problema simples com alinhamento CSS

Tags: css

Ola, sou novo nisso, então estou tendo muitos problemas com essa float.

Quero fazer algo assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha tentativa:

```css
.ant{
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.logo{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.prox{
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/860/original/ant.png?1509538781" class="ant"/>
    </a>

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/858/original/logo.png?1509538726" height="112px" height="212px" class="logo"/>
    </a>

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/862/original/prox.png?1509538834" height="112px" class="prox"/>
    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não usa `position: absolute;` junto com `float`, basta fazer assim.

```css
.ant{
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.logo{
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.prox{
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/860/original/ant.png?1509538781" class="ant"/>
    </a>

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/858/original/logo.png?1509538726" height="112px" height="212px" class="logo"/>
    </a>

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/862/original/prox.png?1509538834" height="112px" class="prox"/>
    </a>

</div>
```

Ou você tambem pode fazer dessa maneira

```css
#head{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.ant{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.logo{
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 130px;
}

.prox{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/860/original/ant.png?1509538781" class="ant"/>
    </a>

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/858/original/logo.png?1509538726" height="112px" height="212px" class="logo"/>
    </a>

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/862/original/prox.png?1509538834" height="112px" class="prox"/>
    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para uma solução menos semântica e manutenível use `flexbox`

```css
#head {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.ant,.prox {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.logo{
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/860/original/ant.png?1509538781" class="ant"/>
    </a>

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/858/original/logo.png?1509538726" height="112px" height="212px" class="logo"/>
    </a>

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/156/862/original/prox.png?1509538834" height="112px" class="prox"/>
    </a>

</div>
```

[Guia completo](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Prefixagem(opcional)](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)